# How to implement Combinations in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, math, combinations

How to implement combinations of permutation & combination in angular 2+.

Eg. we have 5 nodes. Say a,b,c,d,e. And all are arrays.
So the combination goes like -
5C2 = (5)! / (2)!*(3)! = 10.

Now how to make the looping for -

```
a->b
a->c
a->d
a->e

b ->c
b->d
b->e

c->d
c->e

d->e
```

where -

```
a = [claimRequest, claimBody]
b = [ claimBody, eventType]
c= [ claimRequest ]
d= [ headerRequest, claimRequest]
e = [eventType]
```

Now my query is 
where i have to input the two combinations are in place of value1 and value2

```
 RETURN algo.similarity.jaccard(<value1 >, <value2>) AS similarity
```

Comment: like in javascript :)

Comment: @Eliseo is right, Angular is irrelevant in your case...

Comment: Take a look at [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript). With slight alternation it might be exactly what you're looking for.